# Android Studio - Failed to instantiate one or more classes

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am new to Android Studio and I am building an events page project and I am coming across an error. I have tried clearing the cache and project clean to no avail.

I am a complete beginner.

I think the errors are coming from My Gradle coding but I'm not 100% sure if that is the case. Could someone assist me with my coding below and maybe guide me to the correct coding.

Thanks in Advance.

**My Gradle Code**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.desievent.eventapp'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.desievent.eventapp"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    def mdcVersion='1.0.0'
    def recyclerviewVersion='1.1.0'
    def glideVersion = "4.11.0"
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", includes: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:${mdcVersion}"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:${recyclerviewVersion}"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:${glideVersion}"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:compile:${glideVersion}"

}
```

**My Events Page Code**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/smokyWhite">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/smokyWhite"
        >


        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="@string/dashboard_title"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/expandedBarTextStyle"
            >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_app_bar_background"
                android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dashboard_heading"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"


                ></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/dashboard_sub_title"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    >
            </TextView>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:height="50dp"
                    android:hint="@string/search_bar_hint"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/search_bar_background"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/search_btn"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    ></EditText>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">


                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            </LinearLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <!-- will be implementing recycler view instead of nested scoll view -->

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">


    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Errors in the events page code**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:221)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:196)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:131)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:72)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewUtilsLollipop.setStateListAnimatorFromAttrs(ViewUtilsLollipop.java:45)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout.<init>(AppBarLayout.java:183)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:351)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:200)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:161)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:294)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:437)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:341)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:353)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:450)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:122)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:727)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$9(RenderTask.java:884)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:195)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:293)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes
```

Comment: Check style.xml and AndroidManifest. Error log says all you need: "The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant)"

Does your theme is a descendandt of Theme.AppCompat?